# How to display each frame of video transmitted over the network using QML

Tags: qt, video, qml

We all know how to play local video using QML,just like:

```
 MediaPlayer{
    id:player
    source: fd.fileUrl
    autoPlay: true
    volume: voice.value
 }
 VideoOutput {
     anchors.fill: parent
     source: player
 }
```

But what shall i do if i want to display video transmitted from Internet,and before showing on the screen,i have to process each frame of video.

Comment: If you have the link to the video then you should establish it directly, there is no difference: `source: video_url`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't state it clearly, actually i do have the link to the video,but before showing i might do some processing.So,the real video to display is not the same as original one and in this case directly set source may not work.

Comment: So you want to process the image, for example, invert colors, before showing it. For that case the video is local or remote is irrelevant or does your processing only work if the video is local and not if the video is remote?

Comment: yeah,you are right,the video is local or remote is irrelevant.May be my question can be expressed as:how to bind MediaPlayer.source with memory that i applied for and written  with Video Data

Comment: then edit your question since your current question is confusing